# SQL Server - Index maintenance for index with uniqueidentifier?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I got some non-clustered indexes (unique) with uniqueidentifier (GUID) as column. The index gets a lot of fragmentation all the time.

How should I solve this with Ola Hallengren´s maintenance script?

Skip reorg/rebuild of these index?

The problem is described here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2011/08/30/another-reason-of-index-logical-fragmentation/

Comment: Please explain the your problem here in the question instead of posting a link to other website.

Answer (score 0):

here you have two options:

> Very basic information.
>
> 1. `DBCC DBReindex:` locks up the tables and users may not be able to access the data until the reindex is done. Bottom line - this drops
>      the indexes and creates them from scratch. You have brand new indexes
>      when this is done, so they are in the 'best state' possible. Again, it
>      ties up the database tables. This is an all or nothing action. If you
>      stop the process, everything has to rollback.
> 2. `DBCC INDEXDEFRAG:` Does not lock up the tables as much. Users can still access the data. The indexes still exist, they are just being
>      'fixed'. If this is stopped, it doesn't rollback everything. So the
>      index will be less defragged than when you started.
>
> If you run DBReindex, you don't need to run INDEXDEFRAG. There's
>   nothing to defrag when you have brand new indexes.

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I think in this instance you should exclude these from Ola Hallengren's maintenance script. Also Guids should not be part of any clustered index.